# Calculate all coordinates on a line in a set direction from 3d coordinate

Tags: java, 3d, coordinates

I've been looking for a way to identify coordinates along a line given a starting coordinate and a direction. I'm must not be searching using the right terms.

In a Minecraft-style game with blocks, I'm trying to identify all blocks in a single line from the player's viewpoint.

Given an origin x,y,z coordinate, a yaw/pitch (which direction the player is looking), how can I properly identify all coordinates that fall on the resulting "line".

I've been trying variations of the following code. While certain circumstances produce the right results for the x/z blocks being checked, it's wrong most of the time. I've disabled changes to Y for now to keep it simpler for me.

```
// Set base coords of camera
int baseX = (int)pos.x;
int baseY = (int)pos.y+1;
int baseZ = (int)pos.z;

// Set radians of yaw/pitch (direction we're facing)
int range = 1;
double yawRadians = yawDeg * Math.PI / 180;
double pitchRadians = pitchDeg * Math.PI / 180;

System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
System.out.println("Moved to: " + pos.x + " " + pos.z + " facing " + yawDeg);

// Find the next 5 blocks in the direction we're looking (starting at camera pos)
int reach = 5;
for( int i = 0; i < reach; i++ ){

    baseX = (int)(Math.cos(yawRadians) * range + baseX);
    baseZ = (int)(Math.sin(yawRadians) * range + baseZ);

        //baseY = (int)(Math.cos(pitchRadians) * range + baseY);

    WorldTile checkTile = world.getTileAt(baseX, baseY, baseZ);

    if( checkTile == null ) break;

    checkTile.setType(Block.stone);

    System.out.println("Checking " +baseX+ " " + baseY + " " + baseZ + " found " + checkTile.getType().getName());

}
```

The above produces the following results:

```
Moved to: -12.468772 16.442091 facing 357.29998874664307
Checking -11 13 15 found stone
Checking -10 13 14 found stone
Checking -9 13 13 found stone
Checking -8 13 12 found stone
Checking -7 13 11 found stone
```

It indicates that I moved to x:-12, z: 16 (facing north). North = positive Z coordinate changes so while this code is properly producing a series of numbers, it's behind me, and the x coord should remain the same number since I'm looking almost directly north.

Comment: What is not working?  Please show some actual data that demonstrates the problem.  What direction is `dir == 0.00`?

Comment: The above example is from a 2d project, but my trig skills are dusty and I'm not sure how to expand it for 3d. I've tried adding a third cos/sin/tan method to get the new Z but none of them give me the proper values. I tried flattening the x/z into a single value which would work for the cosine method, but means the equation becomes 3d again.

Comment: Updated with the sample code I'm toying with